Smallest prime q such that concatenation (p+q)"q is a prime
Let p, q, and c := (p + q)"q (where " denotes concatenation) be positive integers such that p and c are primes and q is the smallest prime such that c is prime.
Such a prime triple (p, q, (p + q)"q) is for example (9721, 101, 9822101).
In natural order, the results start 3, 7, 3, 3, 19, 3, 31, ...
Challenge
Write a function that, given p, returns q that satisfies the above conditions.
Make sure that the program can calculate the given example in a reasonable time (say in 99 seconds).
Rules
Standard I/O rules apply and no standard loopholes.
This is code-golf, so shortest code in bytes wins.


Postscript
This sequence has an interesting addition: if you run through the sequence and pick out a number as it first appears, you get a sequence that the author of A375552 conjectures to be a permutation of the prime numbers.

First 300 terms

https://oeis.org/A375553

"If you run through the sequence and pick out a number as it first appears, you get a permutation of the prime numbers" is a really convoluted way to say "The sequence contains every prime number".

@Daniel Wagner Maybe you should read up on the difference between 'injective' and 'bijective'. By the way, your user picture shows very nicely what you obviously like to do.

Vyxal gr, 45 bitsv2, 5.625 bytes
Þp'⁰+Jæ

Try it Online!
Bitstring:
001010110100000101000111110000010010001101100

Þp'⁰+Jæ­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
Þp        # ‎⁡a list of infinite primes
  '       # ‎⁢filtered by
   ⁰+     # ‎⁣(p+q)
     J   # ‎⁤(p+q)"q
       æ  # ‎⁢⁡is prime


Created with the help of Luminespire.
Try it Online!
Bitstring:
00101011010000010100011111000101000101101101110110

7 bytes without vyncode, some filter magic.
-1 from r flag

JavaScript (ES6), 59 bytes
p=>eval("for(d=q=1;q<d--|q%d&&n%d?1:d=n=d-1&&[++q+p]+q;)q")

Try it online!
faster / more readable, 61 bytes
p=>{for(d=q=1;q<d--|q%d&&n%d?1:d=n=d-1&&[++q+p]+q;);return q}

Try it online!
p => {              // p = input prime
  for(              // loop:
    d =             //   d = divisor
    q = 1;          //   q = the prime we're looking for
    q < d-- |       //   if q is less than d (decrement d afterwards)
    q % d           //   or d is not a divisor of q
    &&              //   AND
    n % d ?         //   q is not a divisor of n:
      1             //     keep searching
    :               //   else:
      d = n =       //     update d and n:
        d - 1       //       if d is not equal to 1 (meaning that
        &&          //       either q or n is composite):
        [++q + p] + //         increment q and build the new
        q;          //         candidate number
  );                // end of for()
  return q          // return q
}                   //

recursive, 55 bytes
p=>(g=d=>q<d--|q%d&&n%d?g(d):d-1?g(n=[++q+p]+q):q)(q=1)

Try it online!

Japt, 13 11 bytes
@°s+X*j)j}a

Try it, run all test cases or check the first 1000 terms
@°s+X*j)j}a     :Implicit input of integer U
@               :Function taking an integer X as argument
 °              :  Postfix increment U
  s+            :  Convert to string and append
    X*          :    X multiplied by
      j         :      Is X prime?
       )        :  End string conversion and convert back to int
        j       :  Is result prime?
         }      :End function
          a     :Get the first integer >=0 that returns truthy


Charcoal, 36 bytes
Ｎθ≔³ηＷ⊙⟦ηＩ⁺Ｉ⁺ηθＩη⟧⊙…¹÷κ²¬﹪κ⊕⊗μ≧⁺²ηＩη

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
Ｎθ

Input p.
≔³η

Start with q=3.
Ｗ⊙⟦ηＩ⁺Ｉ⁺ηθＩη⟧⊙…¹÷κ²¬﹪κ⊕⊗μ

Check that both p and (q+p)&q are prime by trial division of all odd numbers.
≧⁺²η

If not then add 2 to q and try again.
Ｉη

Output the found value of q.
The golfiest code I could find was to switch to Wilson's theorem for prime checking but this is even slower than odd divisor checking, however it does at least let me save a further byte (and cause even more slowdown) by checking all integers rather than odd ones:
Ｎθ≔³ηＷ⊙⟦ηＩ⁺Ｉ⁺ηθＩη⟧﹪⊕Π…²κκ≦⊕ηＩη

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Only shows an input of p=11 as the given test case would take too much time to compute (even p=419 is too slow).

05AB1E, 8 bytes
∞Ø.Δ+y«p

Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
∞        # Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,...]
 Ø       # Map each to their 0-based n'th prime number: [3,5,7,...]
  .Δ     # Find the first prime in this list that's truthy for:
    +    #  Add it to the (implicit) input-integer
     y«  #  Append the current prime to this sum
       p #  Check if that is a prime itself
         # (after which the found result is output implicitly)

Although we skip prime 2 in the infinite list, since the infinite list starts at 1 and the n'th prime builtin is 0-based, it doesn't matter for the challenge, since appending a 2 to the sum will always result in an even number, and therefore never a prime.

Python, 97 bytes
g=lambda x:all(x%i for i in range(2,x))
f=lambda p,q=2:q if g(q)*g(int(f'{p+q}{q}'))else f(p,q+1)

Attempt This Online!

Rust, 167 159 158 157 bytes
-1 byte thanks to ceilingcat
let g=|n|{if n==2{return 1}for i in 2..n{if n%i<1{return 0}}1};let f=|p:i32|{for q in 2..{if g(q)>0&&g(format!("{}{q}",p+q).parse().unwrap())>0{return q}}0};

Attempt This Online!

Ruby, 69 bytes
->p{2.step.find{|q|(2...r="#{q+p}#{q}".to_i).all?{|x|r*q%x>0||x==q}}}

Try it online!

Brachylog, 9 bytes
;.+;.cṗ∧ṗ

Try it online!
Explanation
;.+         Input + Output…
   ;.c      …concatenated with Output…
      ṗ     …is prime…
       ∧ṗ   …and Output itself is prime


SageMath, 130 bytes
def g(p): 
 for q in Primes(): 
  if is_prime(q+(p+q)*10^(1+int(log(q)/log(10)))):return q
print([g(p) for p in prime_range(100)])


125
